# Filter out certain colors after plotting data using a colormap

Tags: python, matplotlib, colormap

Using the below code I have made the data to be plotted using only the upper half (0.5 to 1) of the default 'jet' colormap, the range of the colormap being 0 to 1. 
If I want the data to show colors only between the range of 0.7 - 1, how do I do it?

```
  import numpy as np
  import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
  from matplotlib.colors import LinearSegmentedColormap
  np.random.seed(1)
  # Evaluate an existing colormap from 0.5 (midpoint) to 1 (upper end)
  cmap = plt.get_cmap('jet')
  colors = cmap(np.linspace(0.5, 1, cmap.N ))

  # Create a new colormap from those colors
  cmap2 = LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list('Upper Half', colors)

  z = np.random.random((4,4)) 

  fig, axes = plt.subplots(ncols=2)
  for ax, cmap in zip(axes.flat, [cmap, cmap2]):
      cax = ax.imshow(z, cmap=cmap, origin='lower')
      cbar = fig.colorbar(cax, ax=ax, orientation='horizontal')
      cbar.set_label(cmap.name)

  plt.show()
```

Result:

[image: result]

I want to get something looking like

[image: expected result]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `vmin` and `vmax` argument. Define the ranges in a list called `vlst` which are 0-1 for the left figure and 0.7-1 for the right figure.

```
vlst = [[0, 1], [0.7, 1]]

fig, axes = plt.subplots(ncols=2)
for ax, cmap, v in zip(axes.flat, [cmap, cmap2], vlst):
    cax = ax.imshow(z, cmap=cmap, origin='lower',vmin=v[0], vmax=v[1])
    cbar = fig.colorbar(cax, ax=ax, orientation='horizontal')
    cbar.set_label(cmap.name)

plt.show()
```

[image]